# How to enable save as option in photoshop using powershell?

Tags: powershell, pdf, photoshop

I want to be able to use powershell to open a pdf in photoshop and save as eps file.
I have saveas working for word and excel, just not sure how to do it with photoshop.

Here is what I use to open the document in photoshop through powershell

```
$ps = New-Object -ComObjectPhotoshop.Application
$ps.Open('C:\temp\RA102001.pdf')
```

This works ok, and opens photoshop and the file correctly, just cant find the saveas option

Here is how it works for word as a reference:

```
$Document.saveas([ref] 'C:\temp\RA102001.pdf',[ref] 17)
```

Comment: This doesn't help you, but why exactly are you trying to accomplish this? Photoshop is not a PDF editor and in general it's a bad idea to use Photoshop as a PDF interpreter. There are usually beter ways to go from PDF to EPS...

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for com-objects are different for each application so you can't expect to be able to use Word's syntax for other applications.

The save as-method in `Photoshop.application` is accessed using:

```
$ps.ActiveDocument.SaveAs
```

I don't have Photoshop so I can't help you further. The options/parameters depend on format etc. You can read more in the [scripting guide for Photoshop cs5](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop_cs5_scripting_guide.pdf#page32). The VBS samples are the one relevant for you as they use the ComObjects too.